# Compare booleans in tuples created with zip

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell.

What I want to do is the XOR operation: I get 2 boolean lists and I `zip` them, getting a list of tuples of booleans. Now I want to compare the elements inside of the tupels.

E.G.

```
list1 = [true, true, false]

list2 = [true, false, false]

list 3 = zip list1 list2
```

Now from this list I wanna get a list `list4 = [false, true, false]`. So if in a tuple in the list there are a `true` and a `false`, in the solution list it would be `true`, else `false`. How can I do this?

Comment: This should be a simple application of `map` together with a function that compares if the two elements of the pair are the same or not

Comment: how can i use map in this case? maybe i don't understand what map does but i don't see it.

Comment: `zipWith (/=) list1 list2`

Comment: sounds like perhaps you don't understand what `map` does, in which case all I can suggest is to look it up, eg [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#maps-and-filters) is a brief explanation with some good examples. (The entire book by the way is the best introduction to Haskell that I know.)

Comment: @Alec - yes, good point :)

Comment: i kinda understand what map does but not with tuples. like.. how do i access a tuple? if i wanna increment every element by 3 i do +3 but what do i do if i wanna compare 2 booleans in a tuple?

Comment: you write a function of type `(Bool, Bool) -> Bool` which checks if the two components are equal or not

Comment: To access a tuple in a lambda, you destructure it like you would lists: `\(x, y) -> f(x, y)`.  You can also provide a named function that takes a bool, bool tuple and returns a boolean value, like so: `xorTuple (x, y) = x /= y`.  Then you would use `map xorTuple list3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alec commented above, what it looks like you want is something like the [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) function:

```hs
list1 = [True, True, False]
list2 = [True, False, False]
list4 = zipWith (/=) list1 list2
```

That will give you `[False, True, False]` in ghci.  If you wanted to use [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map), then you'd do something like this:

```hs
list1 = [True, True, False]
list2 = [True, False, False]
list3 = zip list1 list2
list4 = map (\(x, y) -> x /= y) list3
```